# "git pull" not working from the outside world

Tags: php, git, github

I'm configuring a github web hook to call the below page:

github.php:

```
<?php 

shell_exec('git pull');

?>
```

I have `chmod 777` the file and even `chmod +x` it. When I call `php github.php` from the server everything is good:

```
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 3 (delta 2)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/mynameise/Octo
   afadfb8..1ad3b76  master     -> origin/master
```

But when I try to contact the page it from the outside world using http nothing happens. Also I get no errors in my log file. what is going on?

Comment: Make your hook write the output somewhere, so you get some feedback: `shell_exec('git pull 2>&1 > hook-output.log');`

Comment: @poke hook-output is only created when accessing through the server. when accessing through the web the file isn't even created.

Comment: Does your web server user have permission to execute `git`? Does running the script via your web server from `localhost` work?

Comment: @Chris great question. I don't know how to check it from a web server user has permission. Quite frankly i don't know who is the web server user :/

Comment: Well, trying to trigger the script via HTTP from `localhost` (the machine running the web server) would be a good place to start. If that works, the web server user can run Git.

Comment: @Chris I used `curl` to access the file through the server but it doesn't work. So probably the user doesn't have access to git?

Comment: @Chris how can I change that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45414/discussion-between-chris-and-tom)

Comment: This it because the script hasn't run from git repo root, you need to specify correct git repo path, directly in php code: `git --work-tree=/full/path/to/git/repo --git-dir=/full/path/to/git/repo/.git pull`

Answer (score 0):

This becomes because the script hasn't run from git repository root, you need to specify correct git repository path, directly in *php* code:

```
<?php 

shell_exec('git --work-tree=/full/path/to/git/repo --git-dir=/full/path/to/git/repo/.git pull');

?>
```

**NOTE:** for bare repository you shell to pass only `--git-dir` key value.

Comment: @Tom what the output is it?

Comment: there is no output at all

Comment: @Tom does the `git --work-tree=/full/path/to/git/repo --git-dir=/full/path/to/git/repo/.git pull` work from shell?

Comment: @Tom if you are able to run the command in shell, I believe the problem is in the EVN variable of php, it seems that it can't find the `git` app

Comment: but when I run `php github.php` from the server it works so that's not the problem

Comment: @Tom what do you mean from the server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45487/discussion-between-majioa-and-tom)

Comment: @Tom does the help need yet?